# verify form is filled out, HTML jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I know this is a simple question, but can you all help me with the following code?  I made this function to check that the required fields are filled out in a form.  If it finds one of the inputs is blank, then it should stop and return false.  If all the elements have content, it should return true.  The following function does not work because my `return false;` line is inside the jQuery `.each` function.  It is not returning the new function I defined.  How can I handle this?

```
function check_form(){
    $('form .required').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == ""){
            show_dialog('Please enter a value for ' + $(this).attr('name'));
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

This function is returning true every time even if some required fields are blank.

the problem is described in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f59t4/2/

It works now, thanks everyone!

Comment: 1) Do you want all error messages for all non-filled fields to be displayed in your dialog, 2) Does whitespace-only mean filled?

Comment: See http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/TdnZp/16/ .. its works for text inputs

Comment: YES!! thanks, yeah i posted the wrong fiddle at first, but yes you made it work!  The new one is up there and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
function check_form(){
    var flag = true;
    $('form .required').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == ""){
            show_dialog('Please enter a value for ' + $(this).attr('name'));
            flag =  false;
        }
    });

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: OK cool, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f59t4/1/.  Now how do i get out of the `.each()` function after the first error happens?

Comment: got it: http://gavinroy.com/jquery-tip-how-to-break-out-of-each ... return false.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1) You want a validation summary of all the problems, and

2) You don't want a field containing all spaces to be counted as valid, then:

```
function checkform () {
    var errors = "";
    var $blankFields = $('form .required').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
    });
    if ($blankFields.length) {
        $blankFields.each(function () {
            errors += "Please enter a value for " + $(this).attr('name') + "<br />";
        });
        show_dialog(errors);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  Yes I don't want to allow whitespace either, but I would just like the first error encountered to show up.  Not all the errors together, although I can see how that would be useful in some circumstances.